# How can I define simple nested views within Angular+ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular app with nested views as follows:

```
...<body ng-app="blocksApp">

<div ui-view="full">

    <div ui-view="viewMainMenu"></div>
    <div ui-view="viewHeaderBar"></div>
    <div ui-view="viewMainContent"></div>

</div>

</body>...
```

Regardless of what I do with my ui-router routes I just get "Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" three times, once for each of my 'subviews'.  If I remove the 'parent' ui-view reference then it all starts working, but changing "full" to "" has no effect.  I thought you could have nested ui-views?

My routing looks like this:

```
angular.module('blocksApp')
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

     //For any unmatched url, redirect to this state:
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/default",{
        views:{
            "viewMainMenu":{template:"Purple Main Menu"},
            "viewHeaderBar":{template:"Purple Header Bar"},
            "viewMainContent":{template:"Purple main content"}
        }

    });
    //
    // Now set up the states...
```

The console error looks like this:

```
angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at getUiViewName (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:4117:86)
    at updateView (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:4002:33)
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js:3975:9
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9694:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9093:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8397:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9088:24)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8397:13)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8277:30)
    at lazyCompilation (http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8615:25) <!-- uiView: viewMainMenu -->
```

Can I have simple ui-views nested in this way?  If so, what should my routing look like to support it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nested `ui-view` doesn't work the way you think.

An `otherwise` will only have a URL, like

```
.otherwise("/")
```

will redirect to the main page.

A nested view is in the template of the parent, like so:

`parent.html`

```
<h3>I'm parent</h3>
<p>I'm a paragraph.</p>
<div ui-view="childView1"></div> <!-- in your case - viewMainMenu -->
<div ui-view="childView2"></div> <!-- in your case - viewHeaderBar -->
<div ui-view="childView3"></div> <!-- in your case - viewMainContent -->

<p>I'm another paragraph.</p>
```

And views are only defined in a state:

`routing.js`

```
$stateProvider
     .state('parent', {
         views: {
             'childView1': {template: '<p>A template</p>' }
             'childView2': {template: '<p>A template</p>' }
             'childView3': {template: '<p>A template</p>' }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's because you didn't give a name to your state

try defining the state first:

```
    $stateProvider.state('default', {
        url: '/default',
        views: {
            'view1':{
                template: '<template1>',
            },
            'view2':{
                template: '<template>',
            },
            'view3':{
                template: '<template3>',
            }
        }
    });
```

Then setting the otherwise
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/default");